# Generate vector elements from previous elements

Tags: c++, vector

I would like to build a vector of vectors which is really a tree. I have the seed value and going forward, I multiply the seed with *u* to get the up value and with *d* to get the down value. I have the below snippet that does what I want but can you please suggest a more efficient approach?

```
void short_rate_lattice() {
    double r00 = 0.06;
    double u = 1.25;
    double d = 0.9;
    int num_periods = 5;

    vector<vector<double>> short_rates(num_periods + 1);

    short_rates[0].push_back(r00);
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_periods; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            short_rates[i].push_back(d * short_rates[i - 1][j]);
        }
        short_rates[i].push_back(u * short_rates[i - 1][i - 1]);
    }

    cout << "short_rates vector is populated" << endl;
}
```

Comment: You could preallocate each vector<double> and just do assignment in the loops.  Not sure that would be any faster or efficient though.  This is not a lot of data to begin with.  The code looks efficient as is.

Comment: "*I have the below snippet that does what I want but can you please suggest a more efficient approach?*" - that is a job for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead of StackOverflow.

Comment: You can use `reserve`, `std::transform`, and `std::back_inserter`.